# storing signalr hub connection details in local storage

Tags: signalr, local-storage

I am using signalr client in my application. I want to establish the connection and use the same in all the pages. I could get the connection. To access the hub details i am trying to store it local storage.

Below is the hub details i am getting once i build it.
[image]
        localStorage.setItem("thisConnectionHub",JSON.stringify(thisConnectionHub));

It is stored as below.
[image]

HubConnection is missing in this. Because of this i could not listen to any methods from server.
Any ideas how can i get this work.

Thanks,

Comment: What you mean with ```use the same in all the pages```?

Comment: the established connection hub details which i am trying to store in local storage

Comment: Why you need those hub details?

Comment: i need connected hub details to receive the date from server. Ex : hubdetails.on("methodnamefromserver",function(data){consle.log(data)}).

Comment: But to invoke that method you just need to create a service to connect to the hub and call the method. So you can call the service from any part of your site and get the data.

Comment: but the connection should be established only once. I need to store the established connection, and by using that i need to call the method.

Comment: When your connection is established you don't need to store the connection data. After the connection is established you can invoke any method of your hub.

Comment: i had created a new service file and stored the connection in a method and i could call it. But when i navigate to some other page it is getting called again and establishing a new connection as i had imported that service file in other pages too.

Comment: yes but this is because you can only connect one client at time to your hub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204547/discussion-between-user3667960-and-kiril1512).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same connection, you need to create a `service` that can be @injected in your components so you don't lose the context and can invoke the client side methods that instead will invoke the hub methods. This is called **dependency injection**. Your `service` will establish the connection on the application init and then other components would use the `hubConnection` methods that you will declare public or event implement an interface to do that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I had tried with dependency injection. Now i could get it. But on doing page refresh, method returns empty. I mean the default value null

Comment: Your service must be invoked on the application start, because when you refresh there is no way that you don't need to establish new connection.